# Why ssh shows Desktop folder as a file?

Tags: command-line, ssh, scp, cd-command

I am using `ssh` to accessing a server and I could use `scp` to copy some files to server Desktop by:

```
scp T.tar.gz  username@serverIP:/home/username/Desktop
```

but now I cannot access to server Desktop by `cd` command, and `ls` shows Desktop with white color.
Why Desktop shows as a file instead of a folder?
server has a version 12.04 of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

SSH to your server and see what's up with that Desktop.
Something like this:

```
stat /home/yourname/Desktop
```

Here is mine:

```
$ stat /home/mbiber/Desktop/
  File: ‘Desktop/’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 1572915     Links: 4
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/   marin)   Gid: ( 1000/   marin)
Access: 2014-10-24 18:49:19.090849945 +0200
Modify: 2014-10-23 17:55:12.502627455 +0200
Change: 2014-10-23 17:55:12.502627455 +0200
 Birth: -
```

Main thing is that line which starts with Access should contain 'd' in first parenthesis:

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x) Uid: ( 1000/ marin) Gid: ( 1000/ marin)
```

Comment: It results:  
File:`/home/dvi/Desktop'  
Size: 76687661   Blocks: 149792     IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 656683      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/     dvi)   Gid: ( 1000/     dvi)
Access: 2014-10-25 07:43:11.053292511 -0500
Modify: 2014-10-25 07:33:42.788547757 -0500
Change: 2014-10-25 07:33:42.788547757 -0500
 Birth: -

Comment: Do this `mv /home/dvi/Desktop /home/dvi/Desktop.bck; mkdir /home/dvi/Desktop` and then try transferring the file.

Comment: so what about my old desktop files?
and why this happened?

Comment: Is the problem solved? I don't think you can save your old files. As to why it happened it's most probably your mistake or some bug, maybe FS error... check your logs.

Comment: Now I can access new Desktop and copy my files on it but how could I change my permissions?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/401474/somehow-a-directory-got-converted-to-a-file-how-do-i-change-it-back